# Quiver - scale option

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I tried to use the scale option in the quiver statement in the following way:

```
x=[0 7];
y=[0 0];
u=[1 -1];
w=[1 -1];
quiver(x,y,u,w)

figure(2)
quiver(x,y,u,w,scale=0.5)
```

but the last line does not work .

Error: The expression to the left of the equals sign is not a valid
target for an assignment.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: MATLAB's parameter inputs are not like Python's, they are either implicit in the function syntax or provided using name, value pairs (e.g. `quiver(x, y, u, w, 'Scale', 0.5)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right syntax is: `quiver(x,y,u,w,0.5)`.
In the future look for the documentation ([quiver](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/quiver.html)) for some examples.